# XQUERY-SQL Oracle 12C Concatenate repeated tags

Tags: oracle12c, xquery-sql

new to xquery here.
I'm trying to insert to a table, a list of values from an xml table. 
Question: How do I concatenate `<record>` into 1 db record in 1 column, is that possible? 
Currently I'm getting this error with the SQL query below: ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

XML:

```
<namespace>
<tag1>
 <tag2>
  <records>
   <others>
   </others>
   <others2>
   </others2>
   <record>
   </record>
   <record>
   </record>
  </records>
 </tag2>
</tag1>
```

SQL:

```
SELECT t.FILENAME,
recsdetail.others,
recsdetail.others2,
recsdetail.record
FROM XMLtable t,
XMLTable(
xmlnamespace('blah:blah' as "foo"),
'foo:tag1' PASSING t.filecontent
  COLUMNS "tag2" XMLTYPE PATH '*:tag2/*') rec,
  XMLTABLE(
  xmlnamespace('blah:blah' as "foo"),
'*/*:records'
PASSING rec."rec2"
COLUMNS 
others varchar(10) path '//others'
others2 varchar(10) path '//others2'
record varchar(10) path '//record'
)recsdetail
```

Working on ORACLE 12C Enterprise

Comment: You've told us your object, but what is the question you're asking?

Comment: I want to ask how to concatenate <record> into 1 db record in 1 column.
Currently I'm getting this error with the above query: ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

Comment: Then ask that in your question.